# Has anyone else been able to find out why Back to my Mac isn't working in Yosemite?

Tags: finder, macos, screen-sharing, back-to-my-mac

After upgrading to Yosemite, I can no longer see my other computers that I was able to access with Back to my Mac, under previous OS X versions (while I am away from home - usually accessing my home computer(s) from work).

As each one was upgraded to Yosemite (10.10), each one in turn "disappeared" from being accessible by Back to my Mac. I'm pretty sure its the O/S, but the question is - why?

I didn't change anything, they just don't appear in Finder anymore, but my computers still on Mavericks do appear.  There's also an issue with the local screen sharing, as shortcuts that were created and working under 10.9, are no longer working in 10.10.  I am forced to open Finder and connect that way.  I re-saved the shortcut from screen sharing, but it still doesn't work.

I have the Airport Extreme 802.11ac, firmware 7.7.3

I have tried the [Apple suggested steps](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18990?viewlocale=en_US) with no success.

I'd love to hear from others who can verify this, and perhaps know what Apple changed that broke this for me.

Comment: OK I deleted my answer since it was useless in your case, and Edited more information in your OP for others to see.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, just found this…. Hope this works.
http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18990?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Answers on ask different need to be more than a link. Plinks are okay, but the answer needs to stand on its own if the link breaks.